# java.util.Date get milliseconds

Tags: java, date, time

I have done the following:

```
String standardRange = "00:01:01";
SimpleDateFormat rangeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date range = rangeFormatter.parse(standardRange);
```

Now:

```
range.getTime();
```

.. I get the output of -3539000 and not 61,000

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong; when debugging, `cdate` exists, the attribute contains a `fraction`, which contains the value 61,000, which is what I want.

Comment: This website is in English only, I'm afraid. Please try your best to put it into English, there are always people around to help make it clearer if necessary

Comment: Diese ist Englisch Website, kein Deutsch

Comment: Can you write in English please?

Comment: @Prabhathkesav Party's over

Comment: deleted translation, admins have been faster :D

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html -- the 'h' format character denotes an hour in range 1-12 with an am/pm designation; I'm guessing "00" is interpreted as "-1 hour".

Comment: `setTimeZone()` solves everything

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're seeing this is that the date you're creating is actually in the past of the date epoch, not 1m1s after it:

```
String standartRange = "00:01:01";
SimpleDateFormat rangeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date range = rangeFormatter.parse(standartRange);

System.out.println(new Date(0L));
System.out.println(new Date(0L).getTime());
System.out.println(range);
System.out.println(range.getTime());
```

---

and its output;

```
Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT 1970
0
Thu Jan 01 00:01:01 GMT 1970
-3539000
```

The epoch date is incorrect here - it should be 00:00:00, but due to a [historical bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4832236) where BST/GMT changed dates and timezone cant keep track. It seems that Sun/Oracle consider this a historical "inaccuracy".

Check out the bug report - its describes the problem more fully.

From your language (German) this may not be directly due to this BST issue, but its almost certainly related.

Comment: what he wants is time difference. what he is doing is calculating date. The problem is not actually a bug

Comment: @AdelBoutros well I disagree - I assumed he was after a reason for the behaviour he was seeing, not how to do it.  From the answers here he can choose

Answer (score 1):

Java Date is not designed to calculate the duration of a given time period.
The getTime() call returns the numbers of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. In your case you are actually ending up with a date that comes before that epoch (thus the negative number). When I run your code I get 21661000. (See the answer from [Sean Landsman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067704/sean-landsman) as I believe he has hit on why you get the negative results...hint: my number is exactly 6 hours off of GMT or 21600000ms)

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is a library that is well suited to solving your underlying problem.

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
         .appendHours()
         .appendSeparator(":")
         .appendMinutes()
         .appendSeparator(":")
         .appendSeconds()
         .toFormatter();
Period period = formatter.parsePeriod("00:01:01");
assert period.toStandardDuration().getMillis() == 61000
```

Comment: FYI, Joda-Time offers a trio of classes to represent a span of time: Duration, Interval, and Period.

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want, you should compare between the time you want and origin of the time. using the below code:

```
String standardRange = "00:01:01";
SimpleDateFormat rangeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date range = rangeFormatter.parse(standardRange);
Date range2 = rangeFormatter.parse("00:00:00");
System.out.println(range.getTime() - range2.getTime());
```

Comment: Huh? The number of milliseconds in one hour and one minute and one second is not 61000...

Comment: I like that! It looks like the OP is calculating time difference, so that is absolutely the most correct way to do it (if you don't want to be stuck calculating the times yourself).

Comment: @RudolphEst Exactly. I even read it once but I forgot where that it was the recommended way to always calculate using differences

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaDoc, `getTime()`:

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

You want the number of milliseconds in one minute and one second.

```
(60*minutes+seconds)*1000
```

It really doesn't need to come from a `Date` object.

If you need to compute the time in milliseconds for some interval, maybe use the [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library, or get the day, hour, minute, second and millisecond components out of your date object and compute the value by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Date range1 = rangeFormatter.parse("00:01:01");
Date range2 = rangeFormatter.parse("00:00:00");
System.out.println(range1.getTime() - range2.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

`hh:mm:ss` stands for 12-hour time, which always stands for "time point", not "time interval". So surely, time zone will effect the value. However, in GMT +0 the value equals to which represents "time interval".

All you just need is:

```
rangeFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Try it!